# Javascript: Countdown Timer Within Time Intervals

Tags: javascript, date, countdowntimer

I know many questions like this have been asked, I've yet to find a solution that works or gives me an intuition on how to solve this problem. I know that javascript has a `Date` object, and I can use that as a starting point for the countdown timer.

However I'm not quite sure how to make a counter that follows the following rules:

- We first define three spots on the 24 hour clock to divide the clock
  into 8 hour chunks. Let's say these times are 12AM, 8AM, and 4PM
- We then use the current time to find out which of the three hours
  we're closest to.
- We start a countdown timer from now until that hour, and when the
  timer ends we start another 8 hour timer.

The problem I'm running into is managing the `Date` object. Is there a way to make a countdown regardless of the day, month, and year? My only concern is the time iteself.

Comment: stack overflow is a place for help if you are having troubles, but not a place to write the solution for you. You should provide in your question code examples/methods you are trying at a minimum otherwise your question will be deleted. Everyone can assist you in helping but you need to give some source code.

Comment: @James I've yet to write anything, my apologies for making it seem like I want a solution. My only concern was the `Date` object and how I'm to deal with that.

Comment: No worries, sorry I assumed wrong and only quickly skimmed through question... what you are after can be a little more challenging, not to set the blocks as can define those and do conditions however 2 things which need to think about... do you want date returned for the local web server or do you want to work out based on visitors local timezone? again the blocks you want for ranges.... are they again  set based on server timezone or dynamic based on users timezone?

Comment: To deal with that, I was thinking I force the current time and the destination time to UTC so that everyone viewing the clock will see the same countdown.

Comment: Is there anyway to add time to a `Date` object? I know there are setters, but will incrementing let's say the minute from 11:59PM to 12:00AM increment the day as well? This is the main problem I'm facing.

Comment: From memory Date.UTC()  is what you would be after, of course, if users device clock is wrong might not convert right but cannot see that becoming an issue these days as devices update automatically lol

Comment: maybe have a read up on this good date/time lib (https://momentjs.com/) could be helpful.. of course, most likely can code specifically what you want in not many lines of code but a handy resource for the future if needed

Comment: Everything is possible mate, just the effort you are will to take but in the development world nothing is impossible but yes it is possible, its in jquery as quicker to code but hope this gets you on your way: http://jsfiddle.net/hostandname/x24btrfz/3/